# google charts - geochart

Tags: javascript

Estou tendo um pequeno problema com o geochart, os outros gráficos carregam normal, mais o geo não, ele ate mostra a região do Brasil, mas não popula as regiões. Segue o código:

```
  google.charts.load("44", {packages:["corechart"]});

  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(chartMapDoacoes);

  function chartMapDoacoes(){
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        [`city`, `numedo de doacoes`],
        [`Barueri`, `120442`],
        [`Carapicuiba`, `231298`],
        [`Itapevi`, `213876`],
        [`Jandira`, `128396`],
        [`Sao paulo`, `419226`],
        [`Campinas`, `192381`],
        [`Jundiai`, `391912`],
        [`Jarinu`, `6398212`],
      ]);

    var options = {
    region: 'BR'
    }

    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart-geo'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

e o HTML:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="chart-geo"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: se possível poe so o geo separado de tudo , e alem do seu script o html por favor para que possamos testar

Answer (score 5):

Tente adicionar o código abaixo em suas options:

```
var options = {
        resolution: 'provinces', 
        region: 'BR',
        displayMode: 'markers'
}
```